# Which is more efficient? Loading from memory a full sized bmp or decompressing a png

Tags: android, image, bitmap, compression, png

I'm developing an Android application that's storing a black image the size of the device's screen to the sd card.

I want the stored image to be as **minimally taxing as possible** to the CPU and GPU when rendered.

I'm curious as to what's more efficient:

1. Storing the file as a pure **bmp**, where the CPU reads all **470kB** from flash memory, then hands off to the GPU for rendering.
2. Storing the file as a **png**, where the CPU pulls **9kB** from flash memory, **decompresses it**, then hands off to the GPU for rendering.

Knowing that IO is by far the  biggest bottleneck, I'm inclined to wonder if Method 2 is more efficient. Kind of similar to the way new versions of OSX compress data in RAM when not in use since it's faster to decompress than reload.

Further, if Method 2 is indeed more efficient, does a lossy JPG compression implementation matter since it is all black.. and, would I want to? Is that just more decompression to be done?? Currently I'm using:

```
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, out);
```

I could alternatively use

```
img.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPG, 100, out);
```

with a specified level (0-100, I believe) of compression.

If you have any other tips or suggestions that take advantage of other options within Android since this is about as basic of an image as it gets, it'd be great to hear. (Different bitmap modes, etc..)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Fair question, but remove the "lossy compression" guessing. PNG compression is not lossy – you are confusing it with JPEG. There are levels of compression inside a PNG data stream, but they are related to the efficiency of the Flate algorithm. (Maybe a PNG expert could chime in here, but I think the only factor in getting smaller files is more *compression* time, fairly unrelated to the *decompression* time.)

Comment: Rad Lexus, Thanks for your comment, and good catch! I'm aware that PNG is lossless, but I got confused when I was typing this question because the '100' parameter is ignored -- opposed to when you choose JPG, you can set a level. I'll revise for clarity.